# I'm looking for a book about teens with powers

Tags: story-identification

The book is about the following characters:

- A guy who has flight, super strength and invulnerability to blunt damage.
- A super smart girl.
- A guy who has a black hole / wormhole in his abdomen.
- A girl with cat-like abilities.
- A girl who sticks to things.

It starts in a coffee shop with a poetry slam followed by a fight with an ice-wielding guy. It turns out that the kids are part of an experiment where a serum replaces the polio vaccine given to them as kids.

I've been looking for this book for years, if anyone could help that would be awesome.

Comment: I have no idea what book this is, but it sounds fantastic.  When/where did you first read it? Who is the target audience?

Comment: me too! would definitely love to read it.

Comment: "A guy who has a black hole / wormhole in his abdomen" sounds like Cloak, from _[Cloak & Dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_and_Dagger_%28comics%29)_, but the rest doesn't match.

Comment: i read it about 7 years ago, i think it was teens. i had borrowed it from the library but couldn't find that same book again

Comment: Can you offer any other details? For isntances, were their powers based in science, given by accident, a result of mutation, or magic? Were they all friends originally, or did they have to find each other? Was there a common enemy they had to fight or hide from?

Anything more may help to identify the book